# Oracle DB refresh on 11g using 10g Cold backup

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am a sql dba, I am having only a little knowledge on Oracle. looking for help regarding oracle db restore.
I am having an Oracle 10g cold backup, i need to restore this on Oracle 11g setup, can you please help me understanding the process how to perform.

Comment: You'd need to have an Oracle 10g install that exactly matches the version of Oracle that was used for the cold backup (the same patchset, the same operating system, etc.).  If you wanted to move data from one database version to another, you'd be much better off with a logical backup taken via the export utility (classic or DataPump)

Comment: I think you should be able to restore a 10g database to an 11g system. 
I have restored databases with different patch levels (i.e.11203 to an 11204 system). 
If you have My Oracle Support access, review [doc ID 369644.1](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=369644.1). 
If you don't have MOS access, you can review this [link](https://taliphakanozturken.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/how-to-restore-10g-rman-backup-to-11g/).

Essentially it is the same as restoring a database with the same version, except that there are some "pre-upgrade" tasks and some "post-upgrade" tasks.

Comment: How exactly was this cold backup of yours taken?

Answer (score -1):

Datapump command like **impdp** can be used for importing the 10g DB contents into the 11g DB.

**Update:**

The above datapump command is an example of **logical backup** which can be done when a database is in running mode.
Below are the common steps followed during a logical backup and restore:

1. Export(Backup) of full DB is taken in old server:

   expdp system/password@db10g full=Y directory=DIRECTORY_ON_SERVER dumpfile=DUMPFILE_NAME.dmp logfile=LOGFILE_NAME.log
2. Dumpfile moved to new server
3. Import(Restore) dumpfile in the new server:

   impdp system/password@db11g full=Y directory=DIRECTORY_ON_SERVER dumpfile=DUMPFILE_NAME.dmp logfile=LOGFILE_NAME.log

> More details on this can be found in -->
>   https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g (Better than
>   Oracle docs)

Now coming back to the actual question, what you are asking is a restore of the cold backup in 11g DB server.

The restore of the cold backup can be done by using RMAN command(s) as below:

```
RMAN> restore database from TAG='COLD_BACKUP_FILE_NAME'
```

I assume that you have taken backup of all the necessary files during the cold backup process.

Hope this helps you !!
Please share your progress with regard to this :)

Comment: This answer leaves a lot of room for improvement. Can you provide an example of how to do this so that others can learn?

Comment: @Jcolebrand: Sure. I will try updating my answer.